# String manipulation of Apache Web Server data in R

Tags: r, string

I have a data file of Apache Web Server data, and I want to parse the file and create a dataframe composed of different parts of the log. This will require me to do some string manipulation and usage of regular expressions. However, my experience in string manipulation is very limited.

Each line of the data is one log, like so:

```
[1] "79.133.215.123 - - [14/Jun/2014:10:30:13 -0400] \"GET /home HTTP/1.1\" 200 1671 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36\""
```

For the IP address I used the regexpr function to identify the first space, and then took a substring based upon that first space, like so:

```
> first_space <- regexpr(pattern = " ", text=web_logs)
> IP <- substr(x=web_logs, start=1, stop=first_space-1)
```

However, for the other variables I want to extract I am confused on what I can do. For example, if I wanted to extract the date enclosed by the square brackets, I tried to use regexpr where the pattern = "[", but I received an error.

What other functions can I leverage to extract the information I need?

Comment: What kind of information do you exactly need to extract? Showing your expected result will help SO users to give you a hand.

Comment: For example, say I wanted to retrieve a vector wherein each member is the date. I tried using a substring to do this, but the length of each log is different.

So this code:
'code' Date <- substr(x=web_logs, start = 21, stop=40)
'code' Date[1:2]
Resulted: 
'code' [1] "14/Jun/2014:10:30:13" "[14/Jun/2014:10:30:1"
What I want is:
'code' [1] "14/Jun/2014:10:30:13" "14/Jun/2014:10:30:15"

Here each instance of the variable Date is the full date and time as a character.

Comment: Michael, I understand that. Do you just want to extract date? Or do you want to extract other information as well?

Comment: I also wish to extract the Request (e.g. GET), the Page (e.g. home), and the HTTP version (e.g. 1.1). 

I apologize my comment code is not appearing correctly, I am new to using SO.

Comment: My thought was to use strsplit, but I am unaware of how to extract specific bits inside of the strsplit, if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you try this code? You need to use the stringi package. I called your vector `x`. `stri_split_regex(str = x, pattern = "\"|\\s-\\s-\\s", omit_empty = TRUE)`. See to what extent the output is close to what you want.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webreadr/vignettes/Introduction.html There are R packages for this

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix to your problem, `dplyr` and `tidyr` data manipulation tools can help you. `separate()` will parse your string by simple regex, then you can use `select()` and `merge()` on columns to shape the data frame to your liking.

```
string <- "79.133.215.123 - - [14/Jun/2014:10:30:13 -0400] \"GET /home HTTP/1.1\" 200 1671 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36\""

library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

string.df <- as.data.frame(string) %>%
separate(string, paste0("x", seq(1:(str_count(string, " ")+1))), sep = " ", extra = "merge")
```

Keeping the `extra` argument set to "merge" is for safety - if `separate()` runs out of columns, it will keep everything that is left in the last one.
Result:

```
x1 x2 x3                    x4     x5   x6    x7        x8  x9  x10 x11
1 79.133.215.123  -  - [14/Jun/2014:10:30:13 -0400] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 200 1671 "-"
           x12      x13 x14  x15    x16                x17     x18  x19    x20
1 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows  NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
                   x21            x22
1 Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
web_logs <- c("79.133.215.123 - - [14/Jun/2014:10:30:13 -0400] \"GET /home HTTP/1.1\" 200 1671 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36\"",
              "162.235.161.200 - - [14/Jun/2014:10:30:13 -0400] \"GET /department/apparel/category/featured%20shops/product/adidas%20Kids'%20RG%20III%20Mid%20Football%20Cleat HTTP/1.1\" 200 1175 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.76.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.4 Safari/537.76.4\"")
```

To retrieve the request from the log I combined strsplit() and sapply():

```
split_log <- strsplit(x = web_logs, split=" ")
request <- sapply(split_log, "[", 6)
```

Which returned a character vector, sample below:

```
> request[1:2]
[1] "\"GET" "\"GET"
```

Now all I have to do is drop the \" from request.

Comment: I think you want to arrange your data in your question so that your answer makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by arrange my data?

Comment: Your log sample above does not lead to the output you have in your answer. That is what I meant. You want to have consistency. In the end, your question will become a reference for some people who would have similar situations. You want to consider helping future readers so that you can help them.

Comment: I updated the answer, does it make more sense now? It does not provide an explanation of how to retrieve HTTP or home, but the logic would essentially be the same so I felt it unnecessary.

Comment: You had a typo in `strsplit()`. `weblogs` should be `web_logs`. I cleaned up your code a bit. When you provide data, I recommend you to use `dput()`. This is what they usually do. Showing head is not sometimes enough.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I will keep all of this mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial regular expression to get right. Using http://statmodeling.com/regular-expression-for-apache-log-parsing.html and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html as my guide I came up with this:

```
web_logs <- rep("79.133.215.123 - - [14/Jun/2014:10:30:13 -0400] \"GET /home HTTP/1.1\" 200 1671 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36\"",
                3)

library(stringi)

apache.log.lazy.regex <- "([\\d.]+) ([\\w.-]+) ([\\w.-]+) \\[(.*)?\\] \"(.*)?\" (\\d{3}) ([\\d-]+) \"(.*)?\" \"(.*)?\""
do.call(rbind, stri_match_all_regex(web_logs, apache.log.lazy.regex))[, -1]
##      [,1]             [,2] [,3] [,4]                         [,5]                 [,6]  [,7]   [,8]
## [1,] "79.133.215.123" "-"  "-"  "14/Jun/2014:10:30:13 -0400" "GET /home HTTP/1.1" "200" "1671" "-" 
## [2,] "79.133.215.123" "-"  "-"  "14/Jun/2014:10:30:13 -0400" "GET /home HTTP/1.1" "200" "1671" "-" 
## [3,] "79.133.215.123" "-"  "-"  "14/Jun/2014:10:30:13 -0400" "GET /home HTTP/1.1" "200" "1671" "-" 
##      [,9]                                                                                                           
## [1,] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
## [2,] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
## [3,] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
```

It works for this case, and I think it will generally work in most cases. There are probably examples where it will fail, e.g., if there are embedded quotes in the User-Agent field.